# How to Install extension python 3.3 for PostgreSQL 9.4 WINx64

Tags: postgresql, python-3.3, postgresql-9.4, plpython

I have problem with installing plpython3u for PostgreSQL 9.4
when I write:

```
 CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```

i have this message:

```
ERROR: Could not load the library "C: / Program Files / PostgreSQL / 9.4 / lib / plpython3.dll": unknown error 126
SQL state: XX000
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you install Python 3? See the PostgreSQL download page for Windows, there's a link there to the language runtime installers.

Comment: Yes, i have installed LanguagePac EnterpriseDB for PostgreSQL 9.4. I have still installed PostgreSQL 9.2 with Python 3.2 and i wonder is this is no problem?